# Question about the dative case

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-case, dative

I am studying using the book "Klipp und Klar" and in the lesson fifteen about the dative case there is a sentence that I didn't understand. The sentence is:

> Das Mädchen ist krank und den Frauen ist schlecht.

I realize that the part *den Frauen* is the dative, but is this right? To me this little part should stay in the nominative case, or when the *und* is used the things should stay in the dative.

Comment: The 'und' gives no hint at all as you can connect any two sentences with it.

Answer (score 10):

The sentence is correct; the construction "jemandem ist schlecht" requires the dative case, meaning someone feels nauseated.

This is comparable to "jemandem ist warm/kalt/langweilig"; this also requires the dative case.

If you used the nominative case here, saying "jemand ist schlecht", this would shift the meaning to someone is bad (at something).

Comment: I wouldn't use "jemand ist schlecht" in the context of "someone is bad at something", but rather "someone is bad".

Comment: Even though I agree that the special case of "jemand ist schlecht" can be misunderstood, I want to mention that "jemand" and "jemandem" are both valid dative cases of "jemand".

Answer (score 3):

The fragment 'den Frauen ist schlecht' is dative plural, and to me is sounds like the women are ill or not feeling well - analogous to 'mir is schlecht' when you're not feeling well.

Answer (score 3):

In this case "die Frauen" is the object because it actually means

> Es ist den Frauen schlecht.

This kind of consruction is commonly used when expressing (subjective, usually negative) feeling e.g.:

> Dem Mädchen ist schlecht.
>
> Dem Kind ist langweilig.
>
> Mir ist komisch/ übel/ nicht gut.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences may be connected by "und" or not but they run on different grammar:
Das Mädchen ist krank. WER ist krank? Das Mädchen is the subject of the sentence, das kranke Mädchen. Now: Den Frauen ist schlecht. "WER ist schlecht? ES ist ihnen schlecht." WEM ist schlecht? Den Frauen ist schlecht, they are not feeling well. The non-personal usage of "Es ist..." indicates a condition so you can't say here, die schlechten Frauen. But: If you'd say the women are truly bad people, only then you'd say, "Die Frauen sind schlecht, die schlechten Frauen." Here you'd use the "ist" in a personal meaning which makes the women the subject then. The adjective terms "Das kranke Mädchen/die schlechten Frauen" are necessarily personal terms. Notice the different meanings in personal and non-personal usage !

Comment: There is no "es" in the sentence.

Comment: Also note that while *asking* for the case may be helpful for native speakers, it is of very minor use for learners of the language - If you don't know why something is in a specific case, you most probably also won't know how to ask for it.

Comment: @Carsten:  If there were no "es" there wouldn't be a subject then, thus there must be one ! No complete sentence without a subject. If you reshuffle the sentence into the standard order "Es ist den Frauen schlecht", the subject appears again. -

Comment: @tofro: It's just the other way around: Put up the question first, "Wer? Was? Wen?" etc., then scan the sentence for the proper answer to it. It doesn't matter at first time/place which case there is, just put up all the questions for each case so you will find the corresponding terms and cases.

Comment: @Palmozy, I usually try not to argue about differences between grammar systems when they come to the same conclusions about which sentences are grammatical, but I do not think that it is helpful to claim that German sentences need a subject and then to say that it is sometimes a formal “es” and then that that formal subject can disappear with some word orders. Easier to admit then some German sentences need no subject. https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38585/3237

Comment: @Carsten: As a native speaker of sufficiently good education, I have always observed the must for making up complete sentences, so I still do it today; any sentence without a subject can't be called a sentence. There are many standard sentences which make the subject "es" disappear when changing the standard word order. F.e.: Mir ist kalt - Es ist mir kalt.

Comment: Das ist aber gerade der Punkt. Wir stimmen darin überein, dass "mir ist kalt" ein vollständiger Satz ist. Ich würde nun sagen, dass er zeigt (ebenso wie zum Beispiel "hier wird gefeiert"), dass im Deutschen ein vollständiger Satz kein Subjekt braucht. Du hältst stattdessen an Deiner Regel fest und behauptest, das Subjekt wäre "es", es wäre nur gerade nicht zu sehen. Das erscheint mir unnötig kompliziert. Du müsstest dann auch erklären, warum in "es ist ihnen kalt" das Verb eine Pluralform hat, wenn "es" das Subjekt ist.

Comment: Übrigens, ich habe in der Frage hier auch dazugelernt, ich hatte mir darüber vorher nie Gedanken gemacht.

Comment: @Carsten: Auch ich habe mich wieder etwas schlauer gemacht und gelernt, dass es vereinzelt im Passiv tatsaechlich Saetze ohne Subjekt gibt; dafuer wird das Passiv im Deutschen meist vermieden oder mithilfe von "man" wieder ins Aktiv verwandelt.- Aus meiner Sicht ist ein Satz wie "Mir ist kalt" ein verkuerzter Vollsatz, der eigentlich "Mir ist es kalt" lauten soll; so hat man in meiner Kinderzeit auch gesprochen. Wo das "es" seither abgeblieben ist, frage ich mich schon gar nicht mehr, seit auch das "etwas" meist nur noch als "was" in Verkuerzung daherkommt. "Moechten Sie noch was?" , "Hast du

Comment: Es ist eigentlich eine unter Sprachwissenschatlern akzeptierte Eigenheit der deutschen Sprache, daß ein Satz im Deutschen (im Gegensatz zu den meisten anderen europäischen Sprachen) nicht unbedingt ein Subjekt haben muss. z.B. ist "Im Flur darf nicht gerannt werden" ein korrekter deutscher Satz, bei dem man zwar ein "es" hineinflicken kann, der dadurch aber nicht besser wird. Solange der Sinn transportiert wird und die Verbzweitstellung erfüllt ist, kann man auch ohne Subjekt einen korrekten Satz formulieren.