# Satz ohne Subjekt?

Tags: grammaticality, subject

Mir ist nicht klar, wo das Subjekt in folgendem Satz ist.
Enthält der Satz gar kein Subjekt? Ich habe aber gelesen, dass ein Satz ohne Subjekt nicht vollständig sei. Allerdings habe ich sehr wohl das Gefühl, dass er vollständig ist. Gibt es also Sätze ohne Subjekt, die vollständig sind? Und wenn ja, in welche Kategorie der subjektlosen Sätze gehört der folgende Satz:

> Im nächsten Kapitel wird näher auf die philosophischen und
>   historischen Hintergründe dieses Phänomens eingegangen.

Comment: http://mein-deutschbuch.de/passiv-formen.html

Comment: @Em1 Das ist passive form (werden + perfekt), aber es gibt keine Subjekt in diesem Satz.

Comment: Es gibt auch vollständige Sätze ohne Subjekt: »Mir wird schlecht.«

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kein Subjekt in »Mir wird schlecht«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22845/kein-subjekt-in-mir-wird-schlecht)

Comment: Wie kann "eingehen" eine Passiv-Form haben? "Ich gehe die Tür ein", ist es korrekt?

Comment: Das Verb heisst "eingehen auf", "auf etwas eingehen". Was soviel heisst, wie etwas näher besprechen, etwas näher thematisieren, sich mit etwas näher beschäftigen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es ist möglich grammatikalisch einwandfreie Sätze ohne Subjekt zu bilden, wenn der Handlungsträger nicht relevant ist. In deinem Satz ist scheinbar kein Subjekt vorhanden, doch tatsächlich ist auch in deinem Satz ein formales Subjekt; wenn auch versteckt.

Aufgrund dieser Vorgangspassiv-Konstruktion wird der Handlungsträger für den Satz bedeutunglos und damit ausgelassen. Du kannst aber ein fehlendes *es* ergänzen:

> Es wird im nächsten Kapitel näher auf die philosophischen und historischen Hintergründe dieses Phänomens eingegangen.

Es gibt also Sätze mit verstecktem formalen Subjekt. Lediglich der Imperativ kommt komplett ohne ein Subjekt aus, z. B.

> Verschwinde!

Doch auch hier ist das Subjekt *du* indirekt in der Verbform vorhanden.

Für weitere Beispiele siehe auch [diese](http://www.verbalissimo.com/main/offers/languages/germanic/german/d_german_no_subject.htm) Webseite.

Comment: Pardon, aber ein verstecktes formales Subjekt, das gar nicht da ist, heisst doch einfach, dass der Satz kein Subjekt hat. Man kann ihn so umformen, dass er ein formales Subjekt bekommt. Das Subjekt ist aber erst nach der Umformung da. Vorher hatte der Satz kein Subjekt – was eben bei dieser Art von Sätzen möglich ist.

Comment: @mach: Ich stehe deiner Meinung nahe, aber tatsächlich ist das eine Frage der Interpretation. In vielen Sprachen ist es der Normalfall, dass das Subjekt, sofern es (eigentlich) ein Personalpronomen ist, im Verb eingebaut ist. Z.B. Latein: »Cogito.« ist ein vollständiger lateinischer Aussagesatz, der auf Deutsch »Ich denke.« lautet. Das Subjekt in diesem Satz ist »ego«, aber es lässt sich eindeutig aus der Beugungsform des Verbs erschließen und wird daher weggelassen. Im Deutschen passiert das regelmäßig nur bei Befehlssätzen in der Du-Form.

Comment: Es ist eine Frage des Grammatiktheorie-Geschmacks. Einige Theorien postulieren Satzglieder, die gar nicht da sind. Andere Theorien analysieren die Sprache anhand der vorhandenen Satzglieder.

Comment: Das versteckte formalen Subjekt, das nicht vorhanden ist, scheint mir so etwas zu sein wie Lichtenbergs Messer ohne Klinge, dem der Griff fehlt.

Comment: Es handelt sich hier **nicht**, wie in der Antwort postuliert, um ein verstecktes Subjekt *es.* Wir haben es wirklich mit einem subjektlosen Satz zu tun; nach Umstellung (bei der alle Satzglieder aus dem Vorfeld entfernt werden) muss das Vorfeld lediglich mit einem Expletiv gefüllt werden.

Comment: Die zitierte Seite leugnet im übrigen, daß es immer ein verstecktes Subjekt gibt, und hat damit selbstverständlich recht. "Bei satzgegenstandslosen Sätzen ist in keinem Satzteil ein Subjekt, d.h. ein Wer-Fall (Nominativ), explizit oder implizit vorhanden."

Answer (score 8):

Oft wird im Deutschen angenommen, dass Sätze – wie im Englischen – ein Subjekt bräuchten, um vollständig zu sein. Das ist aber nicht der Fall. Neben den Imperativen (bei denen man argumentieren kann, dass das Subjekt *du* oder *ihr* im Verb eingebaut sei) betrifft das vor allem Sätze im Passiv, bei denen der entsprechende Aktivsatz kein Akkusativobjekt hat.

Grundsätzlich wird das Passiv gebildet, indem Subjekt und Akkusativobjekt des Aktivsatzes die grammatikalischen Funktionen tauschen: aus dem ehemaligen Akkusativobjekt wird das neue Subjekt, das ehemalige Subjekt wird zu einem Präpositionalobjekt. In vielen Sprachen lassen sich daher nur solche Sätze ins Passiv setzen, die auch ein Akkusativobjekt haben (zum Beispiel im Englischen oder Französischen).

Im Deutschen kann prinzipiell jeder Satz ins Passiv gesetzt werden, auch wenn dieser kein Akkusativobjekt hat. Ist keines Vorhanden, so gibt es im Passivsatz keinen Bestandteil, der die Rolle des Subjektes übernehmen könnte; diese bleibt unausgefüllt. Dein Beispielsatz ist einer dieser Sätze. Im Aktiv hätte er lauten können:

> Im nächsten Kapitel **gehe ich** näher auf die philosophischen und historischen Hintergründe dieses Phänomens **ein.**

Verbklammer und Subjekt des Aktivsatzes habe ich fett hervorgehoben. Darüberhinaus enthält er eine Adverbiale des Ortes, eine der Art und Weise und ein Präpositionalobjekt mit *auf.* Wir erkennen: Kein Akkusativobjekt. Folglich bleibt die Position des Subjekts unausgefüllt:

> Im nächsten Kapitel<sup>{Adv. Ort}</sup> **wird** näher<sup>{Adv. Art}</sup> auf die philosophischen und historischen Hintergründe dieses Phänomens<sup>{PräpObj.}</sup> **eingegangen.**

Stilistisch dient der subjektlose Passivsatz – oder besser: Der Passivsatz im Allgemeinen – dazu, den Urheber einer Handlung in den Hintergrund zu stellen, um etwas anderes, wichtigeres hervorzuheben. In deinem Beispiel ist die Person des Autors, die in den nächsten Kapiteln auf etwas eingeht, völlig irrelevant und daher zurecht durch Umformung weggelassen. Wichtig ist stattdessen *dass* und *wo* auf die Hintergründe eingegangen wird.

Man könnte nun argumentieren, dass man den Satz – wie jeden Satz im Deutschen – umstellen könnte und dabei alle Satzglieder zwischen die Teile der Verbklammer setzen könnte. Das ist in der Tat möglich, deutscher Satzbau verlangt allerdings dass ein Satzbestandteil (üblicherweise ein besonders zu betonender) *vor* das finite Verb gestellt werden muss. Um das zu bewerkstelligen, kann das Wörtchen *es* eingesetzt werden. Es scheint sich dabei – wie in diesem Satz, der mit »es scheint« beginnt – um ein Personalpronomen der 3. Person Singular, Neutrum zu handeln. Tatsächlich handelt es sich aber lediglich um ein sogenanntes *Expletiv:* Ein Wörtchen, das nur dazu dient eine sonst unbesetzt bleibende Stelle im Satz zu besetzen.

> **Es** wird im nächsten Kapitel näher auf die philosophischen und historischen Hintergründe dieses Phänomens eingegangen.

Dass es sich bei dem eingefügten *Es* nicht um ein tatsächliches Subjekt handelt, lässt sich an mehreren seiner Eigenschaften festmachen:

1. Sobald ich mich entscheide, ein anderes Satzglied in das Vorfeld zu ziehen, verschwindet das *Es* als sei es nie da gewesen. Hier zwei Sätze zum Vergleich:

   > 1. - **Es** scheint sich um ein Subjekt zu handeln.
   >    - Um ein Subjekt scheint **es** sich zu handeln.
   > 2. - **Es** wird im nächsten Kapitel darauf eingegangen.
   >    - Darauf wird im nächsten Kapitel eingegangen.
2. Ebenfalls verschwindet das *Es* – im Gegensatz zu solchen *Es,* die ein wahrhaftiges Subjekt darstellen – in Nebensätzen, da diese kein Vorfeld haben, das es zu füllen gälte:

   > 1. - **Es** scheint sich um ein Subjekt zu handeln.
   >    - Er sagt, dass **es** sich um ein Subjekt zu handeln scheint.
   > 2. - **Es** wird im nächsten Kapitel darauf eingegangen.
   >    - Ich sagte doch, dass im nächsten Kapitel darauf eingegangen wird.
3. Am wichtigsten wiegt jedoch die Tatsache, dass das *Es* keine Funktion im Satz bekommt, wenn man ihn vom Passiv zurück ins Aktiv setzt. Es kann schließlich keine Form bekommen, es hat ja keine.

   > 1. - **Es** wird eröffnet.
   >    - Ich eröffne **es.**
   > 2. - **Es** wird darauf eingegangen.
   >    - Ich gehe darauf ein.

Wir merken: Passivsätze können im Deutschen tatsächlich völlig subjektlos sein.