# Subject and meaning of the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

> Mit einer PräpP [ mit +Dat/...] kann auf dasjenige, mit dem zusammen etwas genutzt wird, Bezug genommen werden.

I am not able to determine the subject of the sentence and to understand the meaning of the above sentence.

https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/verbs/view/401099/1

Comment: Relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38585/3237

Comment: Ich frage mich, wie Grammatik-Website sich irrt.

Answer (score 4):

First, remove the passive.

> Mit einer PräpP [ mit +Dat/...] kann **man** auf dasjenige, mit dem zusammen etwas genutzt wird, Bezug **nehmen**.

*Bezug nehmen auf* is equivalent to *sich beziehen auf*.

> Mit einer PräpP [ mit +Dat/...] kann man **sich** auf dasjenige, mit dem zusammen etwas genutzt wird, **beziehen**.

This should be easier to process, although the sentence is strangely redundant: It says that *mit* can be used to express the meaning *mit*.

> A prepositional phrase *with ...* can be used to refer to that which is used alongside something else.

The subject of the original sentence presumably is *Bezug*, although this is hard to show. A related sentence where subject-verb agreement shows what the subject is:

> **Man kann** die Gelder ab sofort in Anspruch nehmen.
>   **Die Gelder können** ab sofort in Anspruch genommen werden.