# Kann ein Pronominaladverb als Subjekt eines Satzes verwendet werden?

Tags: grammar-identification, subject, pronominal-adverb

In einem Artikel der Zeit habe ich das Folgende gelesen:

> Die alltäglichen Bürden von Frauen werden weder von der Gesellschaft
>   noch von der Medizin wahrgenommen.**In der Schule wird nicht darüber
>   gesprochen**.

Ich verstehe die zwei Sätze ganz klar - Was nicht darüber gesprochen wird, ist, dass die alltäglichen Bürden von Frauen werden weder von der Gesellschaft noch von der Medizin wahrgenommen. -, aber in Bezug auf die Grammatik bin ich mir nicht sicher ob das Subjekt des zweiten Satzes ein Fall von ***"Null Subject"*** ist oder das Pronominaladverb **darüber** als Subjekt verwendet wird. 
Kann das Pronominaladverb *darüber* als Subjekt verwendet werden?

Comment: Der Satz hat kein Subjekt.

Comment: @CarstenS, ein Satz hat per Definition ein Subjekt.

Comment: Dann haben wir verschiedene Definitionen. https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38585/3237

Answer (score 4):

Ein paar Beispielsätze:

> Mich friert.
>   Dem Jungen ist kalt.
>   Mir wird bange.
>   Der Frau ist schlecht.
>   Ihm wird übel.

Kein einziger dieser Sätze hat ein Subjekt. Und auch diese Beispiele kommen ganz gut ohne Subjekt aus:

> Darüber wird gesprochen.
>   Damit war zu rechnen.
>   Darauf wird geschissen.
>   Woran wird hier gearbeitet?
>   Davor kann nur gewarnt werden!

Die Behauptung, ein Satz bräuchte per Definition ein Subjekt ist falsch. Tatsache ist, dass es gar keine einheitliche Definition des Begriffs »Satz« gibt. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik)#Begriff) verweist auf eine Quelle, wonach es rund 200 verschiedene Definitionen dieses Begriffs gibt.

Comment: auf der Tatasache, dass es kein explizites Subjekt gibt, kann es nicht abgeleitet werden lassen, es gäbe kein Subjekt. Zum Beispiel, wenn man sagt "mir ist übel", ich würde nicht sagen, dass es kein Subjekt gibt. Man könnte behaupten, dass "ein" es bei diesem Satz gibt, obwohl es nicht explizit ist.Und das wäre keine komische Idee. Es gibt ja auch "es geht mir übel". Also, wenn man den Sachverhalt in Bezug auf Logik betrachtet, muss man akzeptieren, dass ein Subjekt gibt.

Comment: ausserdem, in Bezug auf Logik, gibt es eine Regel, die sagt, dass jeder Aussagesatz eine logische Aussage ist. Und jede logische Aussage kann auf verschiedene Weise ausgedrückt werden. Zum Beispiel, "mir ist übel" wäre auf Englisch "I feel sick". Das heißt dann, dass es ein logisches Subjekt gibt. Syntax beruht schliesslich auf Logik.

Comment: @Lalo: Du bringst da gleich mehrere Dinger durcheinander. 1. Schon im ersten Satz sprichst du von der *»Tatasache, dass es kein explizites Subjekt gibt«* und behauptest noch im selben Satz, dass man aus dieser Tatsache eben genau diese Tatsache nicht ableiten könne. Sorry, aber das ist absurd. Man kann gerne über verschiedene Definitionen des Begriffs *»Subjekt«* diskutieren, und vielleicht ein *»syntaktisches Subjekt«,* ein *»semantisches Subjekt«* und ein *»pragmatisches Subjekt«* definieren, aber zu sagen, dass aus man aus der Aussage A genau diese Aussage A nicht ableiten kann, ist absurd.

Comment: Außerdem kannst du nicht einen Satz in eine andere Sprache mit einer anderen Grammatik übersetzen, und dann aus der Tatsache, dass der Satz in der zweiten Sprache anders gebaut ist, Rückschlüsse auf die erste Sprache ziehen. Deutsch und Englisch haben unterschiedliche Grammatiken. Ich kann ja auch nicht daraus, dass beim Übersetzen von *»I'm going«* und *»I go«* auf Deutsch beide Male *»Ich gehe«* wird schließen, dass die beiden englischen Sätze identisch sind oder dasselbe bedeuten. Das ist unsinnig!

Comment: Schönast, in Bezug auf deinen ersten Kommentar kann ich sagen, dass du meine Erklärung nicht verstanden hast. Ich behaupte, dass es nicht-explizite und explizite Subjekte gibt. Demnach, wenn man kein explizites Subjekt sieht, kann man im engeren Sinne nicht sagen, dass es kein Subjekt gibt. Da ein explizites Subjekt eine Art von Subjekten ist, kann es nicht abgeleitet werden, dass es keine andere Arte von Subjekten gibt. Ein anderes Beispiel: Ich kann sagen, es gibt keine weiße Katze , aber daraus kann es nicht abgeleitet werden, dass es keine Katze gibt. Es könnte ja ander Katze geben.

Comment: In Bezuf auf deinen zweiten Kommentar, wie vorher gesagt, laut Theorie der Logik, hat jeder Aussagesatz verschiede Art und Weise bei denen er verkörperlicht werden kann. Laut Logik hat jeder Aussagesatz ein logisches Subjekt. Und das ist so auch, wenn man prima facie das Subjekt nicht sehen kann, also auch wenn es kein explizites Subjekt gibt.

Answer (score 0):

Das Deutsche kennt keine Subjekte in Form von Präpositionalphrasen. Um zu zeigen, das im Beispielsatz kein Subjekt vorliegt, sollte es genügen, auf die Weglaßbarkeit der Präpositionalphrase zu verweisen.

> In der Schule wird nicht (darüber) gesprochen.

Im Gegensatz dazu sind Subjekte nie weglaßbar.

> Deshalb haben **wir** euch (davor) gewarnt.
>   Deshalb wurdet **ihr** (davor) gewarnt.

Daraus folgt, daß das Ausgangsbeispiel kein Subjekt enthält.

Comment: Das Argument des erlaubten Weglassens finde ich gefährlich (auch wenn es hier funktioniert), entdcheidend ist der Erhalt der syntaktischen Struktur. Beispiel: `Der Löwe jagt das Gnu!` - Ohne `Der Löwe` ergibt sich ein grammatisch korrekter Satz, wenn auch mit anderer Struktur und Bedeutung. Trotzdem ist `der Löwe` das Subjekt des ursprünglichen Satzes.

Comment: @collapsar Wie mache ich denn die Struktur dem Fragesteller deutlich? Der Unterschied in Bezug auf Weglaßbarkeit war das Erste, was mir in den Sinn kam. Wenn ich jetzt ergänze, daß sich der Satzmodus nicht ändern darf, wäre das auch nicht genug, wegen *wenn (der Löwe) das Gnu jagt*. Also allgemeiner: Weglaßbarkeit bei Bedeutungskonstanz? Aber das suggeriert eine Operationalisierbarkeit, die ich ohnehin nicht für gegeben halte.

Comment: Die Linguisten setzen dafür eckige Klammern ein, mit denen sie Phrasen abgrenzen. Also `[[Der Löwe] [jagt [das Gnu]]]` ( am Komplementärsatz versuche ich mich mal nicht, der dürfte ein paar funktionale Kategorien / Spuren beinhalten, dafür bin ich nicht tief genug in der Materie ).  Ich weiß aber auch nicht, ob das alltagstauglich ist. Mir ging es nur darum, daß man Regeln, die auf der linearen Abfolge der Worte basieren, mit Vorsicht genießen sollte, also als Heuristiken. Bedeutungskonstanz verwirrt hier glaube ich eher, sie impliziert ja, das gestrichene Wort trage keine Bedeutung im Kontext